# How to ask a single turtle from a link?

Tags: netlogo

I have two breeds of turtles: dogs and cats, and they are linked. The link has an attribute (X), and its value depends on the A value of the dog at the end of the connection (I don't care about cats in this case).

How can I ask the values of attributes of the specific dog to change the link attribute?

I have something like this code, using end2, but sometimes the turtle in end2 is not what I need.

```
ask links [ask end2 
          [
           ifelse A <= 4 [ask myself [set X 1]][ask myself [set X 2]]
          ]]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check out the [asking help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to produce a minimum complete verifiable example- you are more likely to get a useful answer if you follow those guidelines.

One way to do what you need to use the `turtle-set` primitive to have each link bin its two nodes (the cat and dog) into a temporary agent set. Assuming this setup:

```
dogs-own [ A ] 

links-own [ X ]

to setup
  ca
  reset-ticks
  create-cats 10 [
    set color blue
    setxy random 30 - 15 random 30 - 15
  ]
  create-dogs 10 [
    setxy random 30 - 15 random 30 - 15
    set color red
    set A 1 + random 8
  ]
  ask cats [
    create-link-with one-of dogs with [ not any? link-neighbors ] [
      set X 1
    ]
  ]
end
```

First, get the links to create a temporary turtle set out of the two nodes of the link, and choose the agent in that temporary turtle set:

***Edits made thanks to @SethTisue***

**Edit: Don't do this:**

```
to go

  ask links [
    let my-nodes ( turtle-set end1 end2 ) 
    let my-dog one-of my-nodes with [ member? self dogs ]
```

**Edit: Instead do this:**

```
to go

  ask links [
    let my-nodes both-ends 
    let my-dog one-of my-nodes with [ member? self dogs ]
```

That lets the link reference just the dog (`my-dog`) out of its nodes, so it can use `of` to check the attributes of `my-dog` and do what you need.

```
    if ( [A] of my-dog ) <= 4 [   
      set X 2
      ;;; This is just for easy identification
      set color yellow      
    ]
  ]  
  tick
end
```

Comment: `turtle-set end1 end2` can be shortened to `both-ends`

Comment: Thank you @SethTisue, edited to make a note of that.